# Is there any copy update alternative command?

Tags: linux, unix, embedded, cp, busybox

I'm currently using a BusyBox v1.16.2 and *cp* command does not provide update option:

```
...
-u, --update
copy  only  when  the  SOURCE file is newer than the destination file
or when the destination file is missing
```

Is there any alternative?

I would think of using find --newer parameter, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it (after a few tries...).

```
BusyBox v1.16.2 multi-call binary.

Usage: cp [OPTIONS] SOURCE DEST

Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY

Options:
    -a      Same as -dpR
    -R,-r   Recurse
    -d,-P   Preserve symlinks (default if -R)
    -L      Follow all symlinks
    -H      Follow symlinks on command line
    -p      Preserve file attributes if possible
    -f      Force overwrite
    -i      Prompt before overwrite
    -l,-s   Create (sym)links
```

Comment: I see `cp` has `-n, --no-clobber ---> do not overwrite an existing file`. May it be useful for you?

Comment: @fedorqui Busybox provides a limited version of cp. I've added current options for busybox cp. So there is no -n option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test file1 -ot file2 && cp file2 file1
```